# Working with multiple rows from a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination

Before I begin, I want to point out that I can solve my problem. I've rehearsed enough in PHP to be able to get a workaround to what I'm trying to do. *However* I want to make it modular; without going too much into detail to further confuse my problem, I will simplify what I am trying to do so that way it does not detract from the purpose of what I'm doing. Keep that in mind.

I am developing a simple CMS to manage a user database and edit their information. It features pagination (which works), and a button to the left that you click to open up a form to edit their information and submit it to the database (which also works).

What does not work is displaying each row from MySQL in a table using a very basic script which I won't get into too much detail on how it works. But it basically does a database query with this:

```
SELECT * FROM users OFFSET (insert offset here) LIMIT (insert limit here)
```

Essentially, with pagination, it tells what number to offset, and the limit is how many users to display per page. These are set, defined, and tested to be accurate and *they do work.* However, I am not too familiar how to handle these results.

Here is an example query on page 2 for this CMS:

```
SELECT * FROM users OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10
```

This should return 10 rows, 10 users down in the database. And it does, when I try this command in command prompt, it gives me what I need:
[image]

But when I try to handle this data in PHP like this:

```
<?php
    while ($row = $db->query($pagination->get_content(), "row")) {
        print_r($row);

    }
?>
```

$db->query method is:

```
public function query($sql, $type = "assoc") {
    $this->last_query = $sql;
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
    $this->confirm_query($result);

    if ($type == "row") {
        return mysql_fetch_row($result);
    } elseif ($type == "assoc" || true) {
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    } elseif ($type == "array") {
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } elseif ($type == false) {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

$pagination->get_content method is:

```
    public function get_content() {
        global $db;

        $query = $this->base_sql;

        if (!isset($_GET["page"])) {
            $query .= " LIMIT {$this->default_limit}";
            return $query;
        } elseif (isset($_GET["page"]) && $_GET["page"] == 1) {
            $query .= " LIMIT {$this->default_limit}";
            return $query;
        } elseif (isset($_GET["page"])) {
            $query .= " LIMIT {$this->default_limit}";
            $query .= " OFFSET " . (($_GET["page"] * $this->default_limit) - 10);
            return $query;
        }
    }
```

And my results from the while loop (which should print out each row of the database, no?) gives me the same row everytime, continuously until PHP hits the memory limit/timeout limit.

[image]

Forgive me if its something simple. I rarely ever handle database data in this manner. What I want it to do is show the 10 users I requested. Feel free to ask any questions.

**AFTER SOME COMMENTS, I'VE DECIDED TO SWITCH TO MYSQLI FUNCTIONS AND IT WORKS**

```
    // performs a query, does a number of actions dependant on $type
public function query($sql, $type = false) {
    $sql = $this->escape($sql);

    if ($result = $this->db->query($sql)) {
        if ($type == false) {
            return $result;
        } elseif ($type == true || "assoc") {
            if ($result->num_rows >= 2) {
                $array;
                $i = 1;

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $array[$i] = $row;
                    $i++;
                }

                return $array;
            } elseif ($result->num_rows == 1) {
                return $result->fetch_assoc();
            }
        } elseif ($type == "array") {
            if ($result->num_rows >= 2) {
                $array;
                $i = 1;

                while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                    $array[$i] = $row;
                    $i++;
                }

                return $array;
            } elseif ($result->num_rows == 1) {
                return $result->fetch_array();
            }
        }
    } else {
        die("There was an error running the query, throwing error: " . $this->db->error);
    }
}
```

Basically, in short, I took my entire database, deleted it, and remade another one based on the OOD mysqli (using the class mysqli) and reformatted it into a class that extends mysqli. A better look at the full script can be found here:

http://pastebin.com/Bc00hESn

And yes, it does what I want it to. It queries multiple rows, and I can handle them however I wish using the very same methods I planned to do them in. Thank you for the help.

Comment: mysql_* functions again.... come on people :(

Comment: I'm assuming your commenting on my use of "mysql_fetch_row" and others? Well if you're going to say that, at least tell me that I should use mysqli version if it truly makes the difference. From what I've been doing so far, I never really needed to use the newer functions.

Comment: `limit start_rows,rows_to_fetch`. you just keep running the SAME query, fetching the first `$this->default_limit` rows. you need to INCREMENT that value, so you're fetching `limit $current_page,$this->default_limit`.

Comment: but then your still going to run one query for every row - which will be every inefficient

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: you should avoid using those functions, not because you may not need further functionality, but rather they will one day (in the fairly near future) suddenly cease to exist!

Comment: The way I did it before was individually querying a single row, outputting, and then re-querying for the next user. Perhaps what I was doing before was correct and I'm just an idiot.

Before you all start flaming me, I'm going to do some refactoring and exchange the mysql_ functions to mysqli_ instead.

Comment: not at all, it's just harder for me to picture the mistake because I havent used the mysql_functions in forever.. but mysql_fetch_row only ever returns one row.. ask for an array :D

Comment: before jumping to mysqli, make the leap to PDO instead and make your life easier http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: I have no need to use PDO nor do I use any resources that requires me to use PDO. The business I work for uses strictly WAM servers with extensions to other web-based programming languages such as PHP which I develop in. If there is ever any project that uses any other kind of database that isn't MySQL based, then I'll use PDO. No sense constructing a framework that I won't use the functionality for, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using `mysql_fetch_assoc()`:

```
<?php
    while ($row = $db->query($pagination->get_content())) {
        print_r($row);
    }
?>
```

Comment: billy is correct, as commented above, mysql_fetch_row only returns one row

Comment: Yeah, I remember trying to fetch_assoc, no luck there. Give me a moment, I'll retest in a moment.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use fetch_assoc, but puts the page on load. Not exactly sure why this is, but I think my best shot is to refactor how my database works entirely. From what everyone says about using mysql_ functions, apparently mysqli or PDO is the way to go. As for why I use mysql_ functions, its mostly due to habit?

Comment: I can't imagine this not working.  To iterate over rows you need to either use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_fetch_array()`.  The former gives you field names - the only disadvantage being duplicate column names don't work.

Comment: What does "puts the page on load" mean?

Comment: After doing some testing with mysqli and its uses in OOP, I've completely redid my database framework to better suit this new practice (and might I say works 10/10). I edited my original post with the code I used to fix how my database gets queries using mysqli and it does output results exactly how I want them to. Thank you all for the help, and yes, the while loop was exactly what I needed.